# import Excel SpreadSheet data into SQL Server in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have this piece of code, and I am trying to import data from an Excel File to SQL server using ASP.net but it is throwing an error and I cant Figure Out Why?
when compiled it says The Connection String property has not been initialized. any help is appreciated thanks ?

```
protected void LoadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            //Upload and save the file
            string excelPath =  Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);


            string conString = string.Empty;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                    conString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
                    break;

            }
            conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
            using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {


                excel_con.Open();
                string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["toll"].ToString();


                DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();


                dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { 
            new DataColumn("Tag", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Exit",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Location",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Amount",typeof(decimal)) });

                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
                {

                    oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                }
                excel_con.Close();


                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                    {
                        //Set the database table name
                        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MY Table";

                        //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Amount", "Amount");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tag", "Tag");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Exit", "Exit");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Exit", "Exit");
                        con.Open();
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Just guessing. It appears you are setting the `conString` in the switch statement on `extension`. Are you sure one of the `case` clauses gets hit? It may not find any match and since there is no default will remain empty. You may want to check the `conString` after the switch statement.

Comment: yes. handle the default case. and excel files can also have the xlsm extension (macro-enabled). if the file name is empty or extensionless, you could still decide by `PostedFile.ContentType` (mime type).

Comment: but wait: what is `path`? it would have to be the string literal "{0}" to make the `string.Format(conString, excelPath)` work... and are you sure that you persist the uploaded file to a physical path on the server, before you attempt to open? - this is server-side code.

Comment: Thank You for Your help, The file needed to be saved to the server first, be  `string excelpath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/")+ Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelpath);`

Comment: When I try to upload the file into SQL, It goes through but it inserts null values, any suggestion why it is not inserting the values in the excel File I am Uploading?